# casting varchar to numeric in case of null

Tags: sql, casting, int, varchar

How do I handle this conversion if the value is null, so that it does not give the error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric".

```
convert(numeric(19,2), mdmaster.check_no)as checkNbr,
```

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL`:

```
convert(numeric(19,2), ISNULL(mdmaster.check_no, 0))as checkNbr,
```

This will make any `NULL` value be converted to `0.00`.

### [Here is a Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/81974)

Comment: How is this correct?  If `mdmaster.check_no` is NULL, you essentially have `convert(numeric(19,2), '')`, which will still return  "Error converting data type varchar to numeric".

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Sorry `0` will work properly. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ISNUMERIC it will return 0.00 if null

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(50);
SELECT convert(numeric(19,2), ISNUMERIC (@t))as checkNbr
```

or you can use approach as shown below if it matchs your requirement in ms sql server

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN Field NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
        THEN CAST(Field AS INT)
        ELSE NULL 
    END
```

Comment: Doesn't `ISNUMERIC` only take one parameter, regardless of the RDBMS?

Comment: I'm aware of that, but you have `ISNUMERIC (mdmaster.check_no, '')`.  The reference you provided shows a single parameter, yet you are using two.

Comment: @ Littlebobby, you are right.. i just copy pasted you part of query & didnt change the rest.. you can use it as show in Microsoft reference

Comment: In the first example, "ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type." if @t is numeric, checkNbr is 1.00 otherwise it is 0.00. I don't think that works either.